# Can I add Task List items to csHTML in Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, asp.net-mvc-3, tasklist

**Background:**

I am fairly new to Visual Studio 2010 (worked on Lua, LIMSBasic (Labware) and a few others that didn't use decent IDEs and love the idea of task lists being pulled out of the comments I write right in the code.

I have worked out how to use comments to generate all manner of "// TODO:" and other task list and found some good lists on stackoverflow for what type I can do but I can't establish *(no mater how hard I abuse google)* even if it's possible to add them to csHTML files *nevermind how*!

I have tried using all of the following:

```
<!--// TODO: Work out how to add todo stuff to the tasklist!-->
// TODO: Work out how to add todo stuff to the tasklist!
<!--TODO: Work out how to add todo stuff to the tasklist!-->
<!-- TODO: Work out how to add todo stuff to the tasklist!-->
@// TODO: Work out how to add todo stuff to the tasklist!
```

...but nothing was added to the Task List.

**Question:**

So my question(s) is/are: Is it possible to add "TODO:" and other task list item to csHTML (MVC 3 using razor) and if so HOW?

Comment: This is still relevant in January 2024.

Answer (score 73, accepted):

The following should work.

```
@{
    //TODO: do stuff here
 }
```

or

```
@{/* TODO: do stuff here */}
```

As it first has to go into "code" mode, and then you can use a task comment.

But apparently the following does not work (in my visual studio):

```
@*TODO: do stuff here *@
```

Comment: Thanks that was it! I had tried @//TODO but forgot to put it on the list above (added now for future readers).

Comment: In razor it sees @code different than @{code}. @code is equivalent to <%=code%> in aspx syntax, and @{code} is eqivalent to <%code%>

Comment: Oh and @{// TODO: Work out how to add todo stuff to the tasklist!} doesn't work but I'm sure you could work that out as the last } is ignored because of the comment... ;) I't goto be on another line.

Comment: Yes then you should use @{/*TODO: do stuff here */}

Comment: Thanks that looks a bit tidier now it's on one line.

Comment: Any idea why the tasklist items only show when the page is open in VS? As soon as I close that specific cshtml file (leaving it in the project and solution but just closing it) the entry disappears of the tasklist. Obviously that makes it fairly useless!

Comment: Strange, this doesn't work at all for me. Tried the solution as given, and the single line @{/*TODO: do stuff here */}. Anyone else found this?

Comment: @RichardFawcett - are your files open? (See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1663914/todo-comments-are-not-showing-up-in-the-task-list) - alternatively, you may need to go to 'Tools > Options > Environment > Task List' to check your settings